# Spring boot to always serve from index.html

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I created an spring boot project with angular-cli.  The output jar file looks like below:

```
BOOT-INF
    |- classes
        |- com
        |- static
            |- index.html
```

Now, when I go to the following url

```
http://<ip>:<port>
```

I got redirected to `http://<ip>:<port>/app1` since in my angular route, I configured it to redirect.

But when I try to refresh `http://<ip>:<port>/app1`, I got 404 not found.

Comment: check this answer, it will help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564695/spring-boot-angular-entering-url-in-address-bar-results-in-404?rq=1

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Spring Boot automatically detects `index.html` in the following location `public/static/webapp`.

If you have any controller specifically written a mapping as like this -> `@Requestmapping("/")` it will override the default behavior and it will not show the `index.html` unless you route to `http:\\localhost:8080\index.html`

You might want to create it under this folder structure

`src/main/resources/public/index.html`

Hope this helps!